# Entity Framework code first is best for RAD compared to NOSQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, couchbase

I've been trying NOSQLwith C#. I'm also trying entity framework with SQL Server now.

For NOSQL databases(tried couchbase), I could simply use POCO without worrying about DB. Can Entity Framework code first provide a similar feature?

Are any shortcuts to quickly develop apps fully based on POCO without getting deeply inside databases while using Entity framework just like it is for NOSQL databases such as Couchbase?

Please advise a solution where I can focus only coding and leave the database to be totally taken care of by some framework. I wish this is possible with SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to ask me if you need any more details..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about NOSQL, I haven't used them in actual projects. But I've been using EF Code First for some time now.

I think it's pretty easy to code with EF Code First. You just write POCO classes, add DBSet<T> properties into your Context class, and you're done. You can then query objects with linq, and inserting, updating, deleting is very easy too.

But then, when your POPO classes evolves, you may have to spend some time to learn about Migrations to update the database. It's a one time thing though, and only took several hours of learning for me to make it work.

So, imho, yes, you can develop apps fully based on POCO without getting deeply inside database.

Comment: Something I learnt recently: don't use automatic migration, because if you do, it would be difficult to switch back to the manual way, but you will have to if your project keeps evolving after deploying to production environment.